# Hide the whole empty row of table in VF page when rendered as pdf

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I am showing object fields by using `<table>`,`<tr>` and `<td>` tags in page to show the details in some format. I am using following condition to show data on the page, if field is not blank

```
<tr>
<td><apex:outputLabel rendered="if field is not blank"><td> 
</tr>
```

In this code, if field is blank data is not visible but that row is generated and I am getting blank row between two rows.

How to remove this row dynamically?

Comment: Kindly share your code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tend to do this directly in HTML with some CSS hackery

```
<tr style="display: {!IF(ISBLANK(Field__c), 'none', 'table-row')};">
    <td>Content of your cell</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 16):

You should be able to control the rendering of the row using `<apex:variable>`:

```
<apex:variable var="v" value="" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(TheField__c))}">
  <tr>
    <td><apex:outputLabel rendered="if field is not blank"><td> 
  </tr>
</apex:variable>
```

`<apex:outputPanel>` would probably also work as long as you specify `layout="none"`

Comment: Note that apex:variable is actually working better than apex:outputPanel. The outputPanel tag does give problems when conditionally hiding tr tags in PDFs. The table somehow breaks when using outputPanel but does not when using apex:variable.

Answer (score 0):

For group of elements we can use `apex:outputPanel`

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(TheField__c))}">
  <tr>
    <td><apex:outputLabel rendered="if field is not blank"><td> 
  </tr>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  <tr>
    <td><apex:outputLabel rendered="if field is not blank"><td> 
  </tr>

</apex:outputPanel>
```